# Should we have "what's wrong with my computer" questions?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question

First off, sorry if this question has already been asked, but my searches didn't turn anything up. I see a lot of questions on security.SE that equate to "something is wrong with my computer, did the internet gods send me a virus?" I recognize that some people who know what they are doing ask these questions, but I also see a lot of questions that are obviously asked by people who have no idea what they are doing. Since this is a site "For Information security professionals" (that capital 'I' really bothers me, by the way), should we allow these questions here? I am not saying that some of these questions aren't valid, because there are occasional askers who demonstrate expertise, research, and understanding when asking this sort of question.